# Gmail API HistoryId is not increasing chronologically

Tags: gmail-api

In this [Gmail api documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.history/list) we clearly see the following statements:

1. History results are returned in chronological order (increasing historyId).
2. History IDs increase chronologically but are not contiguous with random gaps in between valid IDs.

I did a `message.list` call on a large mailbox and I am seeing this to not be the case.

| Message ID | Historyid | internaldate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 17fddf08be628452 | 29216912 | 3/31/2022 3:06:40 AM |
| 17fddf08a5b47746 | 29260741 | 3/31/2022 3:06:38 AM |
| 17fddf08a1233c88 | **29254708** | **3/31/2022 3:06:38 AM** |
| 17fddf08470d6012 | **29134895** | **3/30/2022 11:32:50 PM** |
| 17fddf082c135739 | **29216911** | **3/31/2022 3:06:32 AM** |
| 17fddf08278d8193 | **29079901** | 3/31/2022 12:31:24 AM |
| 17fddf07f1db6d26 | **29216910** | 3/31/2022 3:06:36 AM |
| 17fddf07d1d4a8da | 29134894 | 3/31/2022 3:06:33 AM |
| 17fddf07c5e32f18 | 29079900 | 3/30/2022 11:33:01 PM |
| 17fddf07bf4cfa19 | 29254707 | 3/30/2022 11:33:07 PM |
| 17fddf07bf3503c3 | 29260733 | 3/31/2022 3:06:35 AM |
| 17fddf07b05d64b8 | 29079899 | 3/31/2022 3:06:36 AM |

I can clearly see that the historyID is not in increasing order. I searched this issue and ran upon this [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/230652463) where the google representative claimed:

"The first message coming from the user.message.list method is in descending order of date but not of historyId."

Which is also not the case as we can see that some dates are also not in order.

Is there any consistency here or any way to get the results of message.list in some type of order?

```cs
        public static IList<Message> ListUserMessages(ref string nextPageToken, int pageSize)
        {
            UsersResource.MessagesResource.ListRequest request = GmailService.Users.Messages.List("me");

            request.IncludeSpamTrash = false;
            request.MaxResults = pageSize;

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(nextPageToken))
                request.PageToken = nextPageToken;

            ListMessagesResponse response = null;
            IList<Message> messages = null;

            response = request.Execute();
            messages = response.Messages;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(response.NextPageToken))
            {
                nextPageToken = response.NextPageToken;
            }
            else
            {
                nextPageToken = null;
            }
            

            return messages;
        }

        public static IList<Message> GetMessage(IList<Message> listMessages)
        {

            IList<Message> messages = new List<Message>();

            foreach (Message listMessage in listMessages)
            {
                UsersResource.MessagesResource.GetRequest request = GmailService.Users.Messages.Get("me", listMessage.Id);

                request.Format = UsersResource.MessagesResource.GetRequest.FormatEnum.Raw;

                messages.Add(request.execute());
            }

            return messages;
        }
```

Comment: Can you please share the actual script or the steps on how you are retrieving these data so we are able to replicate your process. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @DanF I added the two functions which are relevant here, I removed some of the error handling and other details, but this is the basic flow. The calling function obtains a page of messages from the "ListUserMessages" function and then passes that list to the "GetMessage" function to obtain the message data. This is done until there is no more pages left. I also did not include all of the authentication involved either.